# Redshift how to handle other files in S3 that are not overwrite

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a table in Amazon Redshift and my use case would be to unload this table on row number partition to multiple S3 file locations daily. The files from S3 locations will be loaded to DynamoDB by means of S3DataNode of Datapipeline with parameters of DirectoryPath that is pointing towards the S3 locations updated in above step.

```
unload('select * from test_table where (row_num%100) >= 0 and (row_num%100)<=30')
to 's3://location1/file_'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx'
parallel off
ALLOWOVERWRITE;

unload('select * from test_table where (row_num%100) >= 31 and (row_num%100)<=100')
to 's3://location2/file_'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx'
parallel off
ALLOWOVERWRITE;
```

Day1: there are huge number of rows in Redshift and it created file_000, file_001, file_002 and file_003 in one of S3 location (say location2).

Day2: there is not much of rows in Redshift and it created file_000. Because of `ALLOWOVERWRITE` option that I'm using while unload to S3, there is only overwrite of file_000. but still the other files exists(file_001, file_002, file_003 that were created on Day1) and this is resulting in updating already existing items from files_002 and file_003 to DynamoDB.

How should I copy only overwrite files to DynamoDB?

(Note: If I use MANIFEST on unload, Can the datapipeline S3 DataNode only copies the manifest generated files to DynamoDB ?)

Comment: Whatever process you use to load into DynamoDB should delete the files after it has finished using them. Or, specify a different location each day so that the files are not stored in the same location.

Comment: No, files doesnot get deleted after the S3DataNode copies the files from directorypath to Destinated Dynamo DB Table.
And, using a different location each day means creating a new directory each day, which is not optimal.

Comment: You briefly mention Data Pipeline in your question. Are you using it to copy data from DynamoDB to Amazon Redshift? Feel free to edit your question to add more details about how you are performing the data copy.

Comment: Added details about datapipeline.